Variant of Chebyshev's inequality
This is from Shao (2005). I am interested in how did he obtain the bound (just below line 2.3)
$$
P(S_n\geq 0.7z)\leq \frac{1}{1+(0.7z)^2}
$$
As the Chebyshev's inequality implies
$$
P(S_n\geq 0.7z)\leq \frac{1}{(0.7z)^2}.
$$
I can see that for $\frac{1}{(0.7z)^2}>1,\frac{1}{1+(0.7z)^2}>1$ we can replace it with $\frac{1}{1+(0.7z)^2}$ as both bounds are trivial.
Alternatively, could this be a typo or is there a variant to the Chebyshev's bound.


Chebyshev's inequality can be written as $P(|X-\mu| \ge k,\sigma) \le \frac{1}{k^2}$ for positive $k$ but that is two sided.  The one-sided version of Chebyshev's inequality (sometimes called Cantelli's inequality) is $P(X-\mu \ge k,\sigma) \le \frac{1}{1+k^2}$, which is a smaller value.

Clean and to the point. Thanks. Please put in the  answer so that I can accept!

Chebyshev's inequality can be written as $P(|X-\mu| \ge k\,\sigma) \le \frac{1}{k^2}$ for positive $k$ but that is two-sided.
The one-sided version of Chebyshev's inequality (sometimes called Cantelli's inequality) is $P(X-\mu \ge k\,\sigma) \le \frac{1}{1+k^2}$, which is a smaller value.
